# Weird random errors in Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I've experienced a really weird behaviour when using Netbeans today. Firstly, I get `Error: Could not find or load main class <name of my class>` at random. I know what this means but I don't change anything, it appears and disappears randomly. Secondly, when I modify the code e.g. adding a line `System.out.println("x");` that I am 100% sure should be executed, Netbeans seems to overlook that modification and run the old version of the code (before `System.out.println("x");` was added) so as a result it doesn't get printed.

Both errors appear at random and last for some time, then disappear and appear again and so on. I've been trying to fix them for 2 hours but to no avail. They make me unable to do any work with Netbeans.

EDIT: Reinstalling Netbeans and Java didn't help. When I load the same project in Eclipse, everything works correctly.

Comment: You'd better provide more data: nb version, java version, screenshots, etc.

Comment: Does either problem occur/continue immediately after a "Clean and Build" (Shift+F11)?

Comment: I think it sounds like an issue with the cached version of your code in NetBeans, try to clean and build separately, I personally have issues sometimes when I clean and build, especially when using javaFX.

Comment: @JohnSnow  I also tried reinstalling Netbeans and Java and it didn't help (that would clear the cached version).

Comment: Since many people use Netbeans without experiencing what you've described the problem is certainly your configuration or environment.  Unfortunately, you've provided no real information so while people are willing to help you've made it impossible for anyone to do anything but guess.  @MockerTim asked for version info and though you've edited your post twice since his comment was posted you still haven't given us the bare minimum to go on.  What are you using to build the code?  Ant, Maven, Gradle?

Comment: @RichardSmith the saved classfiles however does not change when you reinstall NetBeans and Java however. Without more information it's hard/impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class has a public qualifier. Also the name of the file and the class containing the main method should be same.

Comment: It has a public qualifier and I didn't change the names. The error may persist for some time, then everything goes back to normal and then it pops up again.

Comment: The class containing the `main` method doesn't need to be `public`.